# Not able to remove data node from elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch contains 6 data nodes and 1 master node

I have tried to remove one data node from the cluster using following method

```json
POST http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings

{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "*.*.*.*"
   }
}
```

**Output**

```json
{
    "acknowledged": false,
    "persistent": {},
    "transient": {
        "cluster": {
            "routing": {
                "allocation": {
                    "exclude": {
                        "_ip": "*.*.*.*"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be grateful

Comment: This is already the correct way to [decomission a node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/modules-cluster.html#cluster-routing-settings). It will start moving shards out from the node and then you can shutdown it. Has it finished moving shards out? Or there are still shards on the node?

Comment: I am hoping that where you have put *.*.*.* you have an actual IP address, and this is just you obfuscating your IP?

Comment: Yes I am using actual data ode ip instead *'s